# Finding domain of square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What is the domain of $\sqrt{6-x^2}$ ?? This is related to class 11 , CBSE mathematics relations and functions chapter.
I got the domain as $$[-\sqrt{6},\sqrt{6}].$$
I want to know the steps and procedures to solve the same.

Comment: I know that √(6-x^2) is greater than zero . After this  , how to proceed?

Comment: it must be $$6-x^2\geq 0$$

Comment: Yeah I know that

Comment: After that step , what should be done??

Comment: Solve the equation for $0$ and you should get two solutions. You can verify the domain is in between those two solutions by substituting a random number (such as $0$) and checking if it is defined there or not.

Comment: Okk I got it thanks

Answer (score 2):

$ {6-x^2}\geq 0$  for square root to return value in real numbers. Thus $6\geq x^2$ . Hence $|x|\leq \sqrt {6}$. Thus the domain is $-\sqrt {6}\leq x\leq \sqrt {6} $

Comment: @ Archis: instead of $x\leq |\sqrt {6}|$ you surely mean $|x|\leq \sqrt {6}$